# Angular - Refresh/Get data after delete

Tags: angular, typescript, get

I've landed on a project in flight using Angular without knowing too much about Angular. I'm currently working on a simple CRUD screen. After deleting a row, how can I then "refresh" the UI? Here are the methods inside my component:

```
    AATList:IAat[];

confirmDelete(): void{
    //this.myService.deleteAAT(this.satNumber).subscribe(data => {this.AATList = data;});
    //this.myService.deleteAAT(this.satNumber).subscribe(() => {this.getAATtEntries(); });
    this.myService.deleteAAT(this.satNumber).subscribe();
    this.getAatEntries();
    this.modalRef.hide();
}

getAATtEntries() {
    console.log("entries");
    this.myService.getAATList().subscribe(data => {this.AATList = data});
}
```

(Added on edit, inside component):

```
openDeleteModal(template: TemplateRef<any>, satNumber: number) {
    this.satNumber = satNumber;
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template, {class: 'modal-sm'});
  }
```

Services:

```
getAATList() {
    return this.httpClient.get<ISmt[]>(environment.ApiEndPoint + '/api/SMTDatas', {withCredentials:true});
}

deleteAAT(satNumber : number) {
    return this.httpClient.delete(environment.ApiEndPoint + '/api/SMTDatas/' + satNumber, {withCredentials:true} )
}
```

(I am using the `HttpClient` from `@angular/common/http` for the services)

I've tried the first three lines in the confirmDelete method without avail. What am I missing here? My grasp of Angular is not good so feel free to point out anything else.

UPDATE:
HTML:

```
    <a class="text-danger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete" (click)="openDeleteModal(deleteTemplate, smt.SMTNumber)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>Delete</a>
...
    <ng-template #deleteTemplate>
      <div class="modal-body text-center">
        <p>Are you sure you want to delete this SAT?</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="confirmDelete()" >Yes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="denyDelete()" >No</button>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
```

Comment: I think you can subscribe modelRef.hide method. Can you please try it and call get method on subscribe. Like this.modelRef.hide().subscribe(result=>{this.getAATtentries();});

Comment: `getAATList` return list of `ISmt` and you assign it to list of `IAat` in `getAATtEntries`, do they have the same fields?

Comment: @ZearaeZ It doesn't appear I can do that. _Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'_

Comment: @WaelAbbas Yes, they do have the same fields

Comment: @ZearaeZ which modal `modalRef` component you are using?

Comment: Just for reference, I'm using `import { BsModalService, BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';`

Comment: You can use `this.modalRef.content.onClose.subscribe(result => {
        console.log('results', result);
    })` here is how you can catch close event for Ngx-Bootstrap dialog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note: Out of feeling responsible, I've added an updated information below the post to give slightly "better" insight

---

**TL;DR:** Read about Subscriptions and Subjects, and on how to establish communication between a component and a service. You can achieve what you want by either making a GET request after making a successful DELETE request, or updating your UI by locally removing the item from your list after making a successful DELETE request.

**Longer version:**

An idea could go as follows:

If you make a change that you'll want to be able to see later on (like 99,9% of the apps) you'll want to make a backend call.

How you update your UI kind of depends on how you'd like to proceed with it, **after you've made the backend call**.

So consider a case where you delete an item from the list. You send a delete request for that particular item, and receive a response from the backend. This response should tell you whether the delete operation you made was successful or not.

Based on this information, you can

1) find the item in the list by iterating through it and delete it locally (quicker)

2) make another GET request to the backend and display the newly updated result after your successful deletion (safer, but you end up making 2 requests for each operation).

How you could approach the "is deletion successful" question depends on your implementation, but I'll share one below.

For this, it would be helpful for you to read about **Subscriptions** and **Subjects** using **rxjs**. I'll be writing by following the 2nd option I mentioned above.

On the service where you're making the call, you can create a Subject. You will use this subject to notify the listeners (meaning whoever's subscribed to this event) about any updates by using the **next** method.

In your service, you can create a new Subject as follows:

```
private _deleteOperationSuccessfulEvent$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();
```

and create a getter for it as follows:

```
get deleteOperationSuccessfulEvent$(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this._deleteOperationSuccessfulEvent$.asObservable();
}
```

When you receive a response for your HTTP DELETE request, based on success or failure, you can emit a true or false value as follows:

```
this._deleteOperationSuccessfulEvent$.next(true);
```

So far we're emitting the information that the delete operation was successful, or not.

But nobody's listening to it yet. So in your **component**, you can create a subscription:

```
deleteOperationSuccessfulSubscription: Subscription;
```

and in your ngOnInit method, you can **subscribe** to the deleteOperationSuccessfulEvent$ created in your service:

```
this.deleteOperationSuccessfulSubscription = this.yourService.deleteOperationSuccessfulEvent$.subscribe(...stuff will come here...);
```

(notice we used the deleteOperationSuccessfulEvent$ value, and not the private _deleteOperationSuccessfulEvent$.)

Now your component is listening to your service's delete.. event. We just need to act on it.

```
this.deleteOperationSuccessfulSubscription = this.yourService.deleteOperationSuccessfulEvent$
    .subscribe(isSuccessful => {
        if (isSuccessful === true) { 
            make a GET request and display the returning data, following similar steps to which we followed so far 
        } else {
            delete operation was NOT successful, you can display an error or retry etc.
        }
    });
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

---

**Update**: When doing all this, some things should be noted from an Angular & rxjs standpoint:

1- Try to not use `.subscribe()` in the typescript code - instead try to use the `.pipe()` operator to handle your logic. Instead, let Angular handle your subscription by using the `async pipe` in your template.
You can add `.catchError(err => ...)` in your `.pipe()` to ensure that you catch your errors and handle them properly.

2- If you really have to use `.subscribe()`, don't forget to unsubscribe from that subscription in `ngOnDestroy() {...}`. Otherwise you're risking having memory leaks in your application.

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.mySubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: This is the best way to do it, if the response from the server to delete was successful and no changes occurred to the rest of the data, then just remove it from the array that populates on the front end. There is no reason to use anymore server resources.

Comment: This helped me a lot on deciding whether to just remove the item or reload the entire list.

Comment: I know this post is a bit older but I have a question. I have built my DeleteRequest exactly as described here but unfortunately I always end up in the else condition. Even if I use if(isSuccessful === false) I end up in the else condition. However, the object is deleted but the list is not updated. Can anyone tell me what could be the reason for this? 
How for example is the variable is Successful?

P.S. I use subscribe instead of pipe

Comment: Hello @Doncarlito87 - I sort of understand what you're describing but not entirely. If you can create a stackblitz example I can take some time to look into your problem :) but from what I read, if you're always ending up in the `else` block, could it be that you're emitting a falsy value (false/0/empty string/null/undefined) from the subject?

Comment: Hello @saglamcem thank you for your reply. The project is quite big and I don't use GitHub either. I think that's why Stackblitz is not really possible.  So I had the variable isSuccessful output and the variable is always null. 
Can I maybe provide the code here? Or should I rather open a new ticket?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I think that you are closing the modal, before the request has been executed. Also assumingly you would want to fetch the list in your **parent**, not in the modal. So first I would delete, hide the modal, listen to modal being closed in parent, and there re-fetch the list... so something like:

```
this.myService.deleteAAT(this.satNumber).subscribe(() => this.modalRef.hide());
```

Then in your parent, listen to the hide:

```
this.modalService.onHide.pipe(
  switchMap(() => this.myService.getAATList())
).subscribe(data => {this.AATList = data})
```

---

ORIGINAL:

When you do this:

```
this.myService.deleteAAT(this.satNumber).subscribe();
this.getAatEntries();
```

`getAatEntries()` is actually fired before the delete has finished (most likely), so you need to chain these requests, you can achieve this with `switchMap`:

```
this.myService.deleteAAT(this.satNumber).pipe(
  switchMap(() => this.myService.getAATList())
)
.subscribe((data: ISmt[]) => this.AATList = data);
```

Comment: oh wait, I didn't see the outcommented code, `this.myService.deleteAAT(this.satNumber).subscribe(() => {this.getAATtEntries(); });` **should** work, but it's not recommended to subscribe inside subscribe. Are you getting any errors, are the both requests even firing correctly and not throwing error?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It appears that the Get is not firing inside the Delete subscribe. No errors are being thrown. If I navigate to another link on the page or refresh the page, the row is no longer visible and also no error is thrown. Is there anything else you'd need to see from the code? Also, I had to tweak the code snippet by adding brackets inside the switchMap around the return but same result, the Get is not firing within the Delete. Any thoughts?

Comment: edited my answer, I did a whole lot of guessing now, so this might not be correct, if it doesn't help, please create [mcve] (which should basically always be done ;) ) Otherwise it's impossible to help.

Comment: I'll try it out and I know. I thought it might have been something dumb on my end or I'd get lucky with one of the answers :)

Comment: That appeared to have deleted and refreshed the UI after I click off the modal manually. I've added additional code to see if that clears anything up. Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onHidden` event for the model (which fired when the modal has finished being hidden from the user) to get load your data as below.

```
constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) {
    this.modalService.onHidden.subscribe(() => {
         // Fired when the modal has finished being hidden from the user
        this.getAATtEntries();
    });
}

confirmDelete(): void{
    this.myService.deleteAAT(this.satNumber).subscribe(() => { this.modalRef.hide(); });
}
```

Comment: This works (to a degree) but I have to click off the modal for the modal to hide and the refresh. Is there something else that might be affecting the hiding action?

Comment: @user94614 didn't get your point, can you describe more about what not working?

Comment: Sorry, when I click yes on the modal, the delete fires but the get and modal do not hide until I click outside the modal (elsewhere on the screen). I did make an edit if that clarifies anything.

Comment: @user94614 where do you call `this.modalRef.hide();`?

Comment: @user94614 try to add `this.modalService.setDismissReason('Yes');` before `this.modalRef.hide();`